# laravel eloquent grouping data by months when date is saved as dd/mm/Y

Tags: laravel-5, eloquent

i have dates stored in the database as text because of the format, i saved it as dd/mm/Y (26/06/2019). now i want to get  an array of all data with laravel eloquent while grouping the data into months. could anybody give an idea on how i can get that done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i ended up using the below and it worked!

```
// Convert the data type to date
$year = date('Y', strtotime($date));
$month = date('m', strtotime($date));

$query = Model::whereId($id)
            ->whereYear('date', $year)
            ->whereMonth('date', $month)
            ->get();
```

The above will get all data in the given year and given month, the first two lines converted the date saved as type 'text' to type 'date'.

Answer (score 0):

you can use DB::row method tor format date

```html
$users = DB::table('users AS u')
            ->select('u.*')
            ->groupBy(DB::raw("DATE_FORMAT(u.created_on, '%Y-%m')"))
            ->get();
```

Comment: didnt work, only brought out the first row, i need it to bring all data but grouped into months